# How to get the location of ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have attached a ContextMenuStrip to a Chart control.

How can I get the chart control coordinates where the top left of the ContextMenuStrip is located when it appears?

This is the point I want to translate to chart coordinates:

[image]

Comment: Pretty unclear what you mean or why it matters.  Use the control's PointToClient() method to map to the chart control's coordinates.  Or maybe Axis.PixelPositionToValue() to map to a chart axis.  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I want to be able to insert a marker at the point where I clicked.

Comment: PointToClient solved it :-) I thought :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer to query the current mouse cursor position in the Opening event of the ContextMenuStrip can deliver the wrong position when opening the strip is delayed a bit.

If you need the really clicked position, remove the ContextMenuStrip from the property of the control and manually open the context menu in the MouseDown event of the control. There you have access to the actual click position.

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var relativeClickedPosition = e.Location;
        var screenClickedPosition = (sender as Control).PointToScreen(relativeClickedPosition);
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(screenClickedPosition);
    }
}
```

`relativeClickedPosition` is the cursor position relative to the control.

Answer (score 1):

I added a ContextMenuStrip_Opening event to the ContextMenuStrip. There I could save the menu popup location.

I did something like this:

```
menuPopupLocation = chart.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
```

then I could use:

```
double dataX = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(menuPopupLocation.X);
double dataY = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(menuPopupLocation.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

These contents were also mentioned in the comments above, and since I just encountered this issue, I would like to add this late answer.

Although the official document says that [the Location property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.location?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#remarks) is not relevant to ContextMenuStrip class, in fact its value is its **screen position**, and also it's easy to convert the position to a position relative to its source control:

```
if (sender is ContextMenuStrip cms)
{
    var screenPosition = cms.Location;
    var relativePosition = cms.SourceControl?.PointToClient(screenPosition);
}
```