# ContextMenuStrip Location Point

Tags: vb.net, point, contextmenustrip

How to open the `ContextMenuStrip` programmatically at the cursor on right mouse button down/clicked over `PictureBox`?

---

I need to open `ContextMenuStrip` only in some areas of an `Image` (Schedule) in a `PictureBox`, so I disconnected the `PictureBox.ContextMenuStrip` property from the `ContextMenuStrip1` and I'm firing it manually. That means I need to provide a point, which appears to be surprisingly challanging.

My question is similar to "[How to get location of ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178264/how-to-get-the-location-of-contextmenustrip)", but I need to account for both vertical and horizontal scrolling, which it doesn't (unless I messed something).

So when I'm trying something like this (in `PictureBoxPlan.MouseDown`):

```
Dim rpt As Point = Me.PointToClient(PictureBoxPlan.Parent.PointToScreen(e.Location))
```

...it has a fundamental flaw, because the `e.Location` is in context of `Image`, regardless how it is scrolled within the `PictureBox`. I tried to `Form.MouseDown` event, but it's not fired, when [right] clicked on a `PictureBox`.

Just for confirmation, I still need the point in `PictureBox` context to analyze whether the `ContextMenuStrip` should be shown or not and to lookup associated ID.

I am now trying to use some constants (may not work if windows "font size" is set to other than 100%) together with scroll bars values, which is not optimal at all.

Comment: Use .Parent does not make sense, delete it.

Comment: Just handle the `MouseClick` event of the control, detect the right button and then call `Show` on the menu.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right with `Parent`, I just accidentally left it there, it was one of some options I tested. But it didn't resolve the issues, since when the window was moved away from top-left corner, the `ContextMenuStrip` would still appear in place, where it would be with window top-left-cornered.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for your suggestion and while I resolved the issue in the meanwhile as per answer bellow, I wonder if you meant to call `Show()` with no parameters? I tested it and that showed the `ContextMenuStrip` in the very top-left corner. Though, I too expected that the default value would be the actual mouse-(right)-click point.

Comment: What I meant was to call `Show` with the appropriate arguments, which you could have determined if you had bothered to read the documentation for the method and see what overloads were available. It should go without saying that you read the documentation. Why would the default be the point you clicked? There's no connection between the two. That happens inside the menu when you create a connection by setting the `ContextMenuStrip` property. Without that connection, you have to tell it where to show. That's easy to do and explained in the documentation.

Comment: Why it would take a [1,1] location on the screen? That's a nonsense, while a click point would make sense, I'd say. But it's not a big deal and yes, I might have missed something. As for docs, I actually did try some other overloads, maybe incorrectly, but I think it didn't work, because the coordinates I could provide were in a different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found what is breaking the logic in the `ContextMenuStrip.Show(Point)` documentation:

> ```
> Show(Point)   
> Positions the `ToolStripDropDown` relative to the specified screen location.
> ```

So the ContextMenuStrip, to my surprise, takes the *screen* coordinates, not the *Form* ones. I then just removed `PointToClient` and everything works as a charm, regardless of window position on the screen or scrollbars position of the `Image` container:

```
Dim rpt As Point = PictureBoxPlan.PointToScreen(New Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y))
```

No need to take into account `PanelPlan.VerticalScroll.Value` or `PanelPlan.HorizontalScroll.Value`.